# Install TTF fonts in Xorg

Tags: xorg, fonts, .ttf

I need to install some truetype fonts on my system, in order to make them available to some old style app (tgif).

I created a new dir in /usr/share/fonts/truetype/mynewfont, copied my TTF files inside, ran mkfontdir and mkfontscale, ran xset fp rehash and fc-cache -fv, but still the new font is not showing up in xlsfonts.

What else can I do?
thanks

Comment: forgot to mention I'm on Ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 1):

Did you use `xset fp+ /usr/share/fonts/truetype/mynewfont` to add the directory to the font path?   (That only lasts for the life of the current X session though, doesn't permanently add the font paths.)